# Using JavaScript's setTimeout to (somewhat) emulate smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to (somewhat) emulate a smooth scroll using JavaScript. I am very close to what I want, but my logic currently makes the window scroll past the section it's supposed to scroll *to* and finally jumps back to it. I think it has something to do with the `setTimeout` I'm using but I can't figure it out.

```js
var linkToAnchor = document.querySelector('a[href="#section-2"]');
var anchor = document.querySelector('#section-2')
linkToAnchor.onclick = function() {
  var i = 0;
  var distance = anchor.offsetTop - document.body.scrollTop;
  console.log("distance to be scrolled: ", distance);
  var pixelJump = 25;
  (function loop() {
    console.log("i: ", i);
    //debugger;
    console.log("current scrollTop: ", document.body.scrollTop)
    if (i + pixelJump > distance) {
      document.body.scrollTop = anchor.offsetTop;
      console.log('its over')
      return;
    }
    if (i > distance) return;
    i += pixelJump;
    scrollBy(0, pixelJump);
    console.log("new scrollTop: ", document.body.scrollTop)
    setTimeout(loop, 50);
  })();
}
```

```css
[class*="section-"] {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.section-2 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-1">
  SECTION 1
  <a href="#section-2">link to section 2</a>
</div>
<div id="section-2" class="section-2">
  SECTION 2
</div>
<div class="section-3">
  SECTION 3
</div>
```

Here's a portion of the debug output from the script:

```
distance:  308
i:  0
current scrollTop:  0
new height:  25
i:  25
current scrollTop:  308 ##### WHY DOES THE SCROLLTOP JUMP TO 308 FROM 0?? ####
new height:  333
i:  50
current scrollTop:  333
new height:  358
i:  75
current scrollTop:  358
new height:  383
```

Comment: Change the anchor's `href` attribute. As it is now, when you click the anchor, the page will be scrolled to the element with id `section-2` automatically.

Comment: @Titus. oh my goodness. I don't know how I would've ever figured that out, as I never remotely thought of that as being the problem. Could you tell me the thought structure you had when trying to answer my question? Also, my code works properly now, so you can add that as an answer.

Comment: Could you instead use `e.preventDefault`? Keep the hash in the href. It's a graceful fallback for non-js users.

Comment: @JoeFrambach, yes! That's what I ended up doing as I needed the hash to make the logic work.

Comment: Glad it worked. I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preventDefault` to stop the browser from scrolling to the anchor on its own. Keep the hash in the href. It's a graceful fallback for non-js users.

```
linkToAnchor.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // ..
};
```